# How to add category in APNS payload in Push Sharp library for interacive notification ios

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I am using [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/) library for sending push notification in ios and it is working fine but now i want to use Interactive notification and need to add "category" in APNS Payload.but i cant find any way to do it.
Please let me know how can i do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 3 of PushSharp you have to build the payload by your own.
I'm using the following code to generate the payload. It uses Newtonsoft.Json to generate the JSON payload including the 'category':

```
//
//  @(#) APNsDeviceToken.cs
//
//  Project:    usis Push Notification Router
//  System:     Microsoft Visual Studio 2015
//  Author:     Udo Schäfer

using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace usis.PushNotification
{
    //  ----------------------
    //  APNsNotification class
    //  ----------------------

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a notification that can be send to a device.
    /// </summary>

    public class APNsNotification
    {
        #region constants

        //  ---------------------
        //  DefaultSound constant
        //  ---------------------

        /// <summary>
        /// The name of the default sound file.
        /// </summary>

        public const string DefaultSound = "sound.caf";

        #endregion constants

        #region properties

        //  --------------
        //  Alert property
        //  --------------

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the alert message to display to the user.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The alert message to display to the user.
        /// </value>

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "alert", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Alert { get; set; }

        //  --------------
        //  Badge property
        //  --------------

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the number to badge the app icon with.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The number to badge the app icon with.
        /// </value>

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "badge", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public int? Badge { get; set; }

        //  --------------
        //  Sound property
        //  --------------

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the sound to play.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The sound to play.
        /// </value>

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sound", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Sound { get; set; }

        //  -------------------------
        //  ContentAvailable property
        //  -------------------------

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether new content is available.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        ///   <c>true</c> if new content is available; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </value>

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "content-available", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public bool ContentAvailable { get; set; }

        //  -----------------
        //  Category property
        //  -----------------

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a string value that represents the notification category.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// A string value that represents the <c>identifier</c> property of the
        /// <c>UIMutableUserNotificationCategory</c> object you created to define custom actions.
        /// </value>

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "category", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Category { get; set; }

        #endregion properties

        #region JsonWrapper class

        //  -----------------
        //  JsonWrapper class
        //  -----------------

        private class JsonWrapper
        {
            #region construction

            //  ------------
            //  construction
            //  ------------

            public JsonWrapper(APNsNotification aps) { Aps = aps; }

            #endregion construction

            #region properties

            //  ------------
            //  Aps property
            //  ------------

            [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "aps")]
            public APNsNotification Aps { get; private set; }

            #endregion properties
        }

        #endregion JsonWrapper class

        #region overrides

        //  ---------------
        //  ToString method
        //  ---------------

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a <see cref="string" /> that represents this instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A <see cref="string" /> that represents this instance.
        /// </returns>

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new JsonWrapper(this));
        }

        #endregion overrides
    }
}

// eof "APNsDeviceToken.cs"
```

Give me some feedback whether the code is useful.

Comment: Thanks for reply. We have done this in pushsharp library it self.This answer should be helpful for others.